# Sending data from ABPeoplePickerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, abaddressbook

I want to link a selected contact (ABReference) from the ABPeoplePickerViewController to an object in core data for a swift app I've been developing. I've been investigating how to do so, but to no luck. I think maybe the delegate sent to ABPeoplePickerViewController can do this. Is this the way to do it? Or would I need to programatically code my own AddressBook?

Comment: You need to "manually" model the fields you want to store in Core Data from the address book record.

Comment: I just want to store the ID of the reference to the object. Then again, the main part is getting the selected record from the ABPeoplePickerViewController to another view for processing

Comment: The ID will be different on different devices for the same iCloud account. For the other question, consult the documentation for the delegate, it's very straight forward.